# 'language' is only available in iOS 16 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, locale

I am newbie for SwiftUI. This code display 'language' is only available in iOS 16 or newer. Anyone can help me?

```
var selectedLanguage: String {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: selectedLanguageKey) ?? Locale.current.language.languageCode?.identifier ?? "en" // Default language is English
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: selectedLanguageKey)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .languageDidChange, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the documentation for [`Locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale), the [`language`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/3952516-language) property was added in iOS 16. If you need to support iOS 15 or later, then use the older API of [`languageCode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293346-languagecode).

You can change the line:

```swift
return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: selectedLanguageKey) ?? Locale.current.language.languageCode?.identifier ?? "en" // Default language is English
```

to:

```swift
return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: selectedLanguageKey) ?? Locale.current.languageCode ?? "en" // Default language is English
```

Or you can use both with the proper version check:

```swift
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: selectedLanguageKey) ?? Locale.current.language.languageCode?.identifier ?? "en" // Default language is English
} else {
    return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: selectedLanguageKey) ?? Locale.current.languageCode ?? "en" // Default language is English
}
```

Though that might be better written as follows to avoid all of the duplication:

```swift
let code: String?
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    code = Locale.current.language.languageCode?.identifier
} else {
    code = Locale.current.languageCode
}
return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: selectedLanguageKey) ?? code ?? "en" // Default language is English
```